# How to solve this? Advice?

Tags: determinant

Edit: My original problem includes a matrix, I'm not sure how to format it here so it'll be a bit messy. I was asked to find det(I+M) and someone told me to add all the columns to the last row? Didn't really get what they meant. 
R1 -> | a+1   b   c   d |
R2 -> |  a   b+1  c   d |
R3 -> |  a    b  c+1  d |
R4 -> |  a    b   c  d+1|

Comment: is something missing from your question? $\det(I+M)=?$ also include the question in the main body.

Comment: Are you asking whether $\det(I+M)=\det(IM)$? If so then no; for example set $M$ to the zero matrix.

Comment: [mathjax help](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) for matrices,  \$begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}\$ produces $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$. As of now, I still do not know what is being asked.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, given:
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c&d\\a&b&c&d\\a&b&c&d\\a&b&c&d\end{pmatrix},\\
$$
the required determinant is:
$$\det(I+M)=\begin{vmatrix}a+1&b&c&d\\a&b+1&c&d\\a&b&c+1&d\\a&b&c&d+1\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{C_1+C_2+C_3+C_4\to C_1}{=}\\
\begin{vmatrix}a+b+c+d+1&b&c&d\\a+b+c+d+1&b+1&c&d\\a+b+c+d+1&b&c+1&d\\a+b+c+d+1&b&c&d+1\end{vmatrix}=\\
(a+b+c+d+1)\begin{vmatrix}1&b&c&d\\1&b+1&c&d\\1&b&c+1&d\\1&b&c&d+1\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{-R_1+R_2\to R_2;\\-R_1+R_3\to R_3;\\-R_1+R_4\to R_4}{=}\\
(a+b+c+d+1)\begin{vmatrix}1&b&c&d\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{vmatrix}=a+b+c+d+1.$$
Note: This is what "someone" suggested to you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M= ev^T$ where $v=\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix}$ and $e$ is the all-one vector.

By [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), we have $$\det(I+M)=\det(I+ev^T)=(1+v^TI^{-1}e)\det(I)=1+a+b+c+d$$

As a practice, perhaps try to perform elementary row/ column operations and see if you can get the same answer. (most likely this is the expected approach and you should try it.)

Remark:

- Adding all the columns to the last row doesn't make much sense to me.
- Perhaps they mean adding all the columns to the last column.

Comment: +1 concise and straight to the point.